# .htaccess Regex HEX match

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm building a system where a user can choose custom colors, hit submit, and view what a template would look like using their color scheme.

An example would be: I allow the user to choose 3 custom colors. Once they hit submit, I would redirect them to http://www.my-site.com/scheme/#000000:#FFFFFF:#666666 which, behind the scenes, would bring them to http://www.my-site.com/index.php?scheme=#000000:#FFFFFF:#666666

I'm looking for a pattern to use in .htaccess so that upon using $_GET['scheme'] in PHP, it would return #000000:#FFFFFF:#666666

Note: I am not opposed to having to remove the "#" character from each color, nor having a different seperation character ":".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^scheme/(#.*)$ index.php?scheme=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @user1298740 - check your access/error log files and let me know what you found as a problem

Comment: I was looking for a more specific match, so first off that didn't really meet that I was looking for; my apologies for not being as specific. I don't have any error logs to look at unfortunately, but I'm resorting to a simple (.*) -- Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1298740 - It is unclear (to me) what you want and what you mean by "this didn't work", as you haven't comment what redirection you are experienced. Anyway - if you want specific pattern redirection, then try `RewriteRule ^scheme/#000000:#FFFFFF:#666666$ index.php?scheme=#000000:#FFFFFF:#666666 [NC,L]`